# raise_if_conflict error occurring when I try to run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I am running windows with Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 4.1.1 installed. In console, when I run `rails c`, it responds with:

```
'raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate railties-4.1.1, \
because activesupport-2.3.8 conflicts with activesupport <= 4.1.1>, \
actionpack-2.3.8 conflicts with actionpack <= 4.1.1>
```

I believe that the gems that I have installed are either too dated or too new, but I am not sure which and I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
activesupport-2.3.8 conflicts with activesupport <= 4.1.1>, \
actionpack-2.3.8 conflicts with actionpack <= 4.1.1>
```

It looks like you're  trying to require somewhere that those two gems be newer versions than they are. Have you tried updating your gems with `bundle update`?

Comment: I tried `bundle update` and it seemed to help, but then it told me to update my enviorment.rb file to Rails 4.1.1, which I did. I then ran `rails c` and it responded with `in 'require': cannot load such file -- initializer`